# manipulate characters with mailx

Tags: linux, email, outlook, sendmail, mailx

I'm writing an email using `mailx`

I wanted to know if it is possible to, lets say, underline some words, or making some words bold, or anything..

I have a file which carries the content of the mail `content.txt`

`content.txt:`

`testing mail`

I'm using this `mailx` command:

`mailx -s "testing" me@gmail.com < content.txt`

I would like to do something, so the word `mail` inside the email received will appear like this: **mail**

I couldn't find any example or tutorial about it,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve that using plain text file, But you can play with HTML encoding `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: Some clients render `_underlines_` and `*bold*` even in `text/plain` but this is nowhere near universal. Plain text is really just the letters of the ASCII table and nothing more. The `text/html` content type is not the only game in town for rich content (meaning, text with formatting) but definitely the most widely supported and understood.